# sudo chown -R root:myusername /var/lib/php/session (what should I put in username)?

Tags: command-line

I'm getting this:

> Cannot start session without errors,
>   please check errors given in your PHP
>   and/or webserver log file and
>   configure your PHP installation
>   properly.

So I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/phpmyadmin-cannot-start-session-without-errors/).

But I have no idea what to put in "username".

This is how it looks when I launch the terminal:

```
alex@alex-System-Product-Name:~$
```

My user is "alex", eg:

```
/home/alex
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `chown` command has the following syntax:

```
chown username:groupname directory
```

So in your example command it is your primary group name you need to put
To determine your current user name issue the command as below on a terminal

```
whoami
```

This will return your current user name. Then issue this command to determine your group memberships

```
groups username
```

Assuming that your username is "alex", run:

```
groups alex
```

You will get something like:

```
alex : alex staff adm cdrom lpadmin admin
```

The first one after the `:` is your primary group. In this example it is "alex".

The command will be:

```
sudo chown -R root:alex /var/lib/php/session
```

Comment: Thanks I think it helped but I'm getting this: `chown: cannot access `/var/lib/php/session': No such file or directory`
'

Comment: Yes, That directory may not be there. The command will work only when the directory present.  So you might have missed some steps in that documentation or some steps before that did not work as expected.

Comment: Usually I do 'ls -l /var/lib/php/session' to list the directory to see current ownership before I change it. Then I will know how to revert it if something gone wrong!. That command will help you to see if the directory present or not as well.

Comment: As per your answer, shouldn't the command be `sudo chown -R alex:alex directory_path` since the username and the first group after the : is alex ?

Answer (score 4):

That would be:

`sudo chown -R root:alex /var/lib/php/session`